# cURL NTLM Proxy Authorization - when logged off

Tags: windows, authentication, curl, proxy, ntlm

I have configured the following batch program to execute at scheduled time using the Task Scheduler. In the Task Scheduler, I have set "Run whether user is logged on or not".

If I run the Task Scheduler task when I am logged in, the curl works. But if I log off then through the Task Scheduler task, curl is not working. It looks like the proxy authentication is failing when logged off.

I have been trying different switches such as --anyauth and --proxy-anyauth but it did not work.

```
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0

@echo off
>log.txt (
    some_exe.exe
call curl.exe -U : --proxy-ntlm --proxy myproxy.com:8080 http://www.google.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the username and password parameters when you are not logged in:

```
call curl.exe -U USERNAME:PASSWORD --proxy-ntlm --proxy myproxy.com:8080 http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Sorry I did not mention the question but the password in clear text is not an option I can choose.

Comment: ntlm authentication w/o a password (aka SSO) depends on the user who is currently logged in to the machine... you can store your credentials in a file on the machine in question (or a network location) and restrict access to yourself and then read this information in your batch script at run time.  The task will run under your account and will be able to read the file.